# Theoretical String Landscape Question

Tags: string-theory, multiverse, string-theory-landscape

Could it be plausible that the same theoretical string "shape" occurs twice. 
As in two or more universes with the same amount of dark energy and string shape.
The term "shape" I'm defining as based on the way Brian Greene was implying in this video:

[Why is our universe fine-tuned for life?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf7BXwVeyWw)

Please forgive my ignorance if this question is nonsensical as I'm very interested in physics but mostly just read around.

Comment: If the "string landscape" and multiverse are accurate, there is nothing stopping there from being two identical universes with the same properties.  That is one gigantic speculative IF though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a bad question. I think as the comment says, the answer is yes, many Universes may have similar properties. However, it has been argued that our Universe's cosmological constant is finetuned, and that this fine tuning has an environmental explanation.

I.e., our constant is untypical, but since observers need e.g. structure in their Universe, we shouldn't be surprised that it is untypical.

Since our constant is untypical, there are relatively few Universes similar to ours in the multiverse picture.